# Find paths in graphs using LINQ only

Tags: c#, linq, graph

This question is about finding a LINQ-Query that extracts a path in an acyclic graph from any given node to any other given node.

Please note this is about LINQ only (to demonstrate its power or show its limitations)

Assume the following classes to represent a Graph `G = (V,E)`

**DataStruc**

```
    internal class Vertice
    {
        private Int32 id;

        public Vertice(Int32 id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Int32 GetId()
        {
            return this.id;
        }
    }
    internal class Edge
    {
        private Int32 id;
        private Vertice v1;
        private Vertice v2;

        public Edge(Int32 id, Vertice v1, Vertice v2)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
        }

        public Vertice GetFirstVertice()
        {
            return this.v1;
        }
        public Vertice GetSecondVertice()
        {
            return this.v2;
        }
        public Int32 GetId()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

        public Boolean ConnectedTo(Vertice v)
        {
            if (v.GetId() == this.v1.GetId()) return true;
            if (v.GetId() == this.v2.GetId()) return true;

            return false;
        }

        public Boolean Connects(Vertice u, Vertice v)
        {
            if (!this.ConnectedTo(u)) return false;
            if (!this.ConnectedTo(v)) return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now create a graph as displayed using the code shown below the image (yes, the picture shows a digraph, but let's ignore that for now)

[image: Graph to model]

**Code to create the graph**

```
        // Create Vertices
        List<Vertice> v = new List<Vertice>();
        v.Add(new Vertice(0));
        v.Add(new Vertice(1));
        v.Add(new Vertice(2));
        v.Add(new Vertice(3));
        v.Add(new Vertice(4));

        // Create Edges
        List<Edge> e = new List<Edge>();
        e.Add(new Edge(0, v[0], v[1]));
        e.Add(new Edge(1, v[1], v[2]));
        e.Add(new Edge(2, v[1], v[3]));
        e.Add(new Edge(3, v[1], v[4]));
        e.Add(new Edge(4, v[2], v[4]));
```

and now let's query the graph (v,e)

**Query to extract all edges from v0 to v1**

```
        var edge_query =
            from edge in e
            where edge.Connects(v[0], v[1])
            select edge;
```

Executing the query gives exactly one edge (id=0). I am now curious whether it is possible to write a LINQ-query that returns multiple sets of edges where each set contains one path from a given node `u` to another given node `v`

Here is the complete code that can be pasted into a `ConsoleApplication`.

Kind regards,
Benj

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create Vertices
            List<Vertice> v = new List<Vertice>();
            v.Add(new Vertice(0));
            v.Add(new Vertice(1));
            v.Add(new Vertice(2));
            v.Add(new Vertice(3));
            v.Add(new Vertice(4));

            // Create Edges
            List<Edge> e = new List<Edge>();
            e.Add(new Edge(0, v[0], v[1]));
            e.Add(new Edge(1, v[1], v[2]));
            e.Add(new Edge(2, v[1], v[3]));
            e.Add(new Edge(3, v[1], v[4]));
            e.Add(new Edge(4, v[2], v[4]));

            // Query Set
            var edge_query =
                from edge in e
                where edge.Connects(v[0], v[1])
                select edge;

            foreach (Edge edge in edge_query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("e" + edge.GetId() + " connects v" + edge.GetFirstVertice().GetId() + " and v" + edge.GetSecondVertice().GetId());
            }

            // Wait for the user to understand
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("[ENTER] to terminate ...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        internal class Vertice
        {
            private Int32 id;

            public Vertice(Int32 id)
            {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public Int32 GetId()
            {
                return this.id;
            }
        }
        internal class Edge
        {
            private Int32 id;
            private Vertice v1;
            private Vertice v2;

            public Edge(Int32 id, Vertice v1, Vertice v2)
            {
                this.id = id;
                this.v1 = v1;
                this.v2 = v2;
            }

            public Vertice GetFirstVertice()
            {
                return this.v1;
            }
            public Vertice GetSecondVertice()
            {
                return this.v2;
            }
            public Int32 GetId()
            {
                return this.id;
            }

            public Boolean ConnectedTo(Vertice v)
            {
                if (v.GetId() == this.v1.GetId()) return true;
                if (v.GetId() == this.v2.GetId()) return true;

                return false;
            }
            public Boolean Connects(Vertice u, Vertice v)
            {
                if (!this.ConnectedTo(u)) return false;
                if (!this.ConnectedTo(v)) return false;

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

ie. when changing the `Edge.Connects`-method to

```
            public Boolean Connects(Vertice u, Vertice v)
            {
                if (this.v1.GetId() != u.GetId()) return false;
                if (this.v2.GetId() != v.GetId()) return false;

                return true;
            }
```

one can use the query

```
            var edge_query =
                from u1 in v
                from edge1 in e
                from edge2 in e
                where edge1.Connects(v_start, u1)
                where edge2.Connects(u1, v_stop)
                select new Tuple<Edge, Edge>(edge1, edge2);
```

to extract all paths from `v_start` to `v_stop` via any vertice `u1` in V. is it possible to extend the query to consider an arbitrary amount of intermediate vertices?

[image]

Comment: Finding a path is a recursive algorithm and can't be done with Linq.

Comment: But would it be possible to find paths of `length <= N` for any given `N`? Is it possible to dynamically create this query based upon a parameter `N`? That way one could search for paths with `length <= card(V)` which would be sufficiently large

Comment: You need to solve using Dijkstra's and how would you be able to mark a node visited using Linq?

Comment: you would not need to mark a node as visited since the graph is acyclic by assumption

Comment: still need recursive algorithm to handle large graphs.